# How replace characters with asterisks (*) except first two characters

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to mask the data returned from the API with Asterisk (*). For example, if an address is to be returned from the API, I want only the first 2 letters to be visible.

**Example**: Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.

**What i want**: Lo*** Ip*** is si**** du*** .....

I created a sample API and I don't know how to find a solution. I thought I could convert text to asterisk with replace, but I have no idea how to make the first 2 letters appear.

**Demo: [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-resonance-dcefc?file=/src/App.js)**

If you have any ideas about what I should do and share it, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it like this

```
const s = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.";

function hideWord(w) {
    if (w.length < 3) return w;
    return w.substring(0, 2) + '*'.repeat(w.length-2);
}

console.log(s.split(" ").map(hideWord).join(" "));
```

Output is

```
Lo*** Ip*** is si**** du*** te** of th* pr****** an* ty********* in*******
```

Split the string into words and then map each word top its hidden version and rejoin. To map it simply return any 1 or 2 letter length words as they were and for others take a substring of the first two chars and fill the rest with asterisks.

You could also wrap the whole lot in a function if you wanted to be able to call it from multiple places and avoid redefining it.

```
function hideWords(s) {
    return s.split(" ").map(hideWord).join(" ");
}

console.log(hideWords(s));
```

Comment: thank you so much!! How can I edit this function so that it can be used everywhere, do you have any idea? Split etc. continuously for separate name, surname and address data. Would it be troublesome to add?

Comment: Maybe just wrap it all in another function. If I understand you correctly?

Answer (score 4):

I would use [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) with [lookbehind assertion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions#other_assertions)

```
const text = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing & typesetting industry';
const result = text.replaceAll(/(?<=\w{2,})\w/g, '*');
```